# lowering filenames from bash script, using awk as a helper

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following script I wrote, for renaming files in current directory,
using `awk`

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script collects filenames from current dir, into list
# and then uses awk to process them, lowering their filenames

[ -f ./tmp.filelist ] && rm tmp.filelist

for file in *
do
    echo $file >> tmp.filelist
done

# if file already not all lowercase, make it lowercase
awk '{ if ($0 != tolower($0))
        printf("mv \"%s\" \"%s\"\n", $0, tolower($0)) | "sh" }

        END { close("sh") }
' tmp.filelist && rm tmp.filelist
```

Is there some better way of escaping those `%s`-es in `printf` before sending
them to shell? I am not interested in better way of doing this, like only shell or something, I want to use `awk` here, and just asking about best way to pass filenames with spaces to shell, whatever might be the case, not just this script.

Comment: To avoid nasty surprises (such as glob expansion) I'd recommend changing `echo $file` to `echo "$file"` in the loop above.

Comment: Cannot happen here, because it writes to file, then when reading awk reads the whole line `$0`, so again no problems, only in a moment when passing that `$0` to shell, I have to escape, because if spaces within, it will split.

Comment: If a filename contains a `*`, it will be interpreted as a glob and the resulting line in the file would contain all of the expansions of the glob. There's no harm in coding defensively.

Comment: Yes you are right about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use awk. In BASH 4+ you can use:

```
echo "${str,,}"
```

OR else:

```
for file in *; do
   mv "$file" "${file,,}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with nested quotes is always a bit of a hassle but another option would be to use something like this. I've chosen to use `system` instead of piping to `sh`:

```
awk '{lower = tolower($0)} $0 != lower {system("mv '"'"'" $0 "'"'"' '"'"'" lower "'"'"'")}' file
```

In bash and awk, strings are concatenated together by default, so the `'"'"'"` ends the first part of the awk one-liner, then adds a single quote (which needs to be wrapped in double quotes), then continues with the awk one-liner. In order to then include the value of `$0`, the double quotes from the `system` command then need to be closed. Looks kind of awkward and is arguably no improvement on what you already had but it *does* avoid escaping.

Compare that with the same method using escaping:

```
awk '{lower = tolower($0)} $0 != lower {system("mv \"" $0 "\" \"" lower "\"")}' file
```

By the way, the structure of awk scripts is `condition { action }` so the `if` statement is redundant. To avoid calling `lower` twice I added an action which happens unconditionally at the start of the script, which stores the value in the variable `lower`.